# What is the name of Android Device Manager Service

Tags: android-device-manager

When you turn on Android Device Manager in Google Settings, it is possible to locate your phone by going to http://www.google.com/android/devicemanager

I have a very small cellular data allowance on the phone, and I want to ensure that only the android device manager service is using cellular data.

I downloaded the NetGuard app, that allows me to control what can use cellular data at a very detailed level, however, I can't work out which service I need to enable for cellular data to make android device manager operational.

Comment: The qualified name for the app is `com.google.android.apps.adm`.

Answer (score 2):

The Android Device manager is by default allowed:

```
<wifi
    blocked="false"
    package="com.google.android.apps.adm" />
<other
    blocked="false"
    package="com.google.android.apps.adm"
    roaming="false" />
```

https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard/blob/master/app/src/main/res/xml/predefined.xml#L19